# How can I set timeout option on every request in page.goto function

Tags: javascript, node.js, chromium, puppeteer

I use puppeteer to scrape resources from a page, but one of the requests does not succeed because of connection timeout, and it blocks the `page.goto('url')` function for a long time. I want to skip this request and continue to request next. I need to set timeout on every request, but not a total timeout option on `page.goto` function.

Follow is my code test.js:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.on('request', request => {
    console.log(request.url())
})
await page.goto(process.argv[2], {timeout: 10000}).then( () => {
}, () => {
    console.log("timeout");
}); 
browser.close();
```

```
node test.js http://ipv6ready.wanwuyunlian.com:8080/

http://ipv6ready.wanwuyunlian.com:8080/  
http://ipv6ready.wanwuyunlian.com:8080/js/bootstrap.min.js
http://ipv6ready.wanwuyunlian.com:8080/js/echarts/echarts.min.js
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js    
http://ipv6ready.wanwuyunlian.com:8080/js/echarts/macarons.js
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
```

The `analytics.js` request is very slow because of connection-timeout; this will block `page.goto` for a longtime, resources left will not be requested, I want to abort this request and continue to request the remaining resources.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can tackle this. The first is to use `networkidle2` ("consider navigation to be finished when there are no more than 2 network connections for at least 500 ms") instead of the default `networkidle0` so that up to two requests can be slow without affecting your code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(process.argv[2], {waitUntil: "networkidle2"}).then( () => {
}, (e) => {
    console.error("Error", e);
}); 
browser.close();
```

Alternatively, to implement timeouts on individual page requests, I would suggest using a timeout module such as `p-timeout`:

```
const pTimeout = require("p-timeout");

const shorterTimeout = 10000;
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', async (request) => {
    if (!shouldImplementTimeout(request.url())) {
        await request.continue();
    }

    await pTimeout(request.continue(), shorterTimeout)
        .catch((e) => {
            console.error(request.url(), "failed:", e);
            await request.abort("timedout");
        });
})
await page.goto(process.argv[2]).then( () => {
}, (e) => {
    console.error("Error", e);
}); 
browser.close();
```

You would need to write `shouldImplementTimeout`, which should return `true` if the request needs a shorter timeout.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just cancel requests based on their URL, there is a mode in puppeteer for that: [page.setRequestInterception](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue). A sample from the docs adapted to your use case:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // turn on requests intercepting and cancellation capability
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {

    console.log(interceptedRequest.url());

    if (interceptedRequest.url().includes("google-analytics.com"))
    {
      console.log("cancelled!");
      interceptedRequest.abort();
    }
    else
    {
      interceptedRequest.continue();
    }
  });
  await page.goto('http://ipv6ready.wanwuyunlian.com:8080/');
  await browser.close();
});
```